# fread and endianness confusion

Tags: c, endianness, fread

So to provide context, my system is little endian and the file that I am reading from is big endian (MIDI format, for those that are interested). I am supposed to read a variety of data from the file, including unsigned integers (8 bit, 16 bit, and 32 bit), chars, and booleans.

So far I know that reading unsigned integers will be an issue with fread() because I would have to convert them from big endian to little endian. My first question is, although maybe stupid to some, do I need to convert chars and booleans as well?

My second question is regarding the entire file format. Since the file is in a different endian system, do I need to read the file from the end towards the beginning (since the MSB and LSB positions will be different)? Or do I need to read in the values from the start to the end, like I would normally, and then convert those to little endian?

Thanks for taking the time to read my post and for any answers that I might receive!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `fread`. Just read the data into memory, then access them using `uint16_t` and `uint32_t`. These types can be easily converted from big-endian to host byte order using `ntohl` and `ntohs` functions. The char is the same in all byte orders.

Comment: I am storing those unsigned integers into their uint_t counterparts. So far, I have 2 methods that swap endianness of 16 bit numbers and 32 bit numbers.  I am calling them each time I read a uint.Does that seem right? I cannot use ntohl and stuff. I am bound by the libraries.

Comment: It would be unsual to have the value for a *pointer* in a file. It is unlikely to point anywhere useful. As for a boolean value, if it occupies more than one byte in the file, then endianness will apply there too.

Comment: It is a bool, so I think it occupies only 1 byte. I apologize for the confusion. There are chars that I read into char pointers.

Comment: Ah, you edited the *pointers* out of the question. For any type that occupies 1 byte of storage, endianness is irrelevant. Reversing the sequence of 1 byte does nothing: it is still the one and only byte. As for the whole file, you do not reverse the sequence, it is as defined.

Comment: But if its an array of chars? Then do I need to worry about endianness? I am sorry but I really dont know much about endianness

Comment: No, [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) concerns the storage of a *single* value that occupies 2, 4, 8... bytes. An array element at index `[0]` is always located at the same address as the array itself is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Endianness only reverses order inside words of a certain length, usually 2, 4, or 8 bytes. If you're reading in a one byte value such as a char or a bool, then endianness has no effect. However, if you're reading in any value that is more than a byte, such as an integer, then endianness matters. You can still use `fread` since endianness has nothing to do with file reading, just make sure to convert from big endian to little endian.

Comment: You'll almost never see middle endian used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

When you read external data that isn't just a sequence of characters, you read it as a sequence of bytes, and construct the actual data that you want from it.

If you expect a signed 16 bit number, followed by an unsigned 8 bit number, followed by an unsigned 32 bit number, you write a function reading two bytes and returns them converted to a signed 16 bit number, one that reads one byte and returns it as an unsigned 8 bit number, and one that reads four bytes and returns them converted to a 32 bit number. Construct the 16 and 32 bit numbers using bit shifting.